# angular scrollIntoView() fine-tuning distance

Tags: angular, scrollto, js-scrollintoview

Angular can slide to the top of the specified element, as shown below:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

However, due to layout issues, if the css `sticky` attribute is at the `top:0`, it may block the element. I hope to adjust the scroll to the top position of the element(Like `top:100px`).

I try to using `window.scrollTo` or `window.scroll`, but it seem not work in angular:

```
    let scrollY =  el.getBoundingClientRect().top + 100;
    window.scrollTo({
        top: scrollY,
        behavior: 'smooth', 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. To make the page scroll smoothly to the desired position, add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to your css:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Now you can scroll to a desired position with `window.scrollTo( y )`, where `y` includes an offset you need.

Don't use `scrollIntoView()` in this case.

Comment: I can achieve the smooth effect through `scrollIntoView()`, but my problem is that I hope you can fine-tune the scroll position, such as increasing or decreasing 100px to the position I want it to scroll to.